# React navigation V5 header button usage

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have react navigation screen as follows .

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
```

I need to navigate  another screen using a right header button how can i do this.
I'am using react navigation V5

Comment: Can you please add your right header button component code ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} />,
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
              title="Info"
              color="#fff"
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

You can also use screenOptions

```
screenOptions={({route, navigation}) => ({
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },
    headerRight: () => (
      <Button
        // only alert is ok, the other is error.
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
        title="Logout"
        color="#fff"
      />
    ),

    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
  })}
```

Comment: thanks , but how to use this right button to navigate another screen